# Characterization of an open set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Question from Royden's Real Analysis.

> Show that a subset $E$ of  a metric space $X$ is open $\iff$ there is a continuous real-valued function $f$ such that $E=\{x:f(x)>0\}$

If $E=\{x:f(x)>0\}$ 
 then $E=f^{-1}[(0,\infty)]$ which is the inverse image of a open set under a continuous function and hence open.

But how to prove the converse part.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E=X$ then set $f(x)=1$ for all $x$.

Otherwise let $E^c$ be the complement of $E$, and define
$$ f(x)=d(x,E^c)=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in E^c\} $$

One can show that $f$ is continuous, and since $E^c$ is closed it follows that $f(x)=0$ precisely when $x\in E^c$.

Comment: Carmichael.Kindly check: f(x) = inf{$d(x,y) |y \in E^c$} =0, implies $x\in E^c$, (closed).Since infimum, there is a sequence $f_n(x) := d(x,y_n)$ converging to 0, $y_n \in E^c$. Implies x is a limit point of$ E^c$. Hence $x\in E^c$, since closed

Comment: Looks good to me.